# Как настроить тестирование на другую бд?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, moq

У меня есть отдельная бд для тестирование, но я не понимаю, как настроить в moq для подключения к другой бд?

бд:

```
public class MySqlContext : DbContext
{
    public MySqlContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        // Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    DbSet<TestObject>
    ...
}
```

И сам moq:

```
var mocqContext = new Mock<MySqlContext>();
var dbObjects = new Mock<DbSet<TestObject>>();
//DbSet<TestObject> testObjects = new DbSet<TestObject>();
mySql = mocqContext.Object;
```

Как передавать в MySqlContext строку для подключения к другой бд, БД у меня postgress, если есть большая разница

Comment: О каком тестировании идёт речь: модульное, интеграционное, ещё какое-то? Moq обычно используется в юнит-тестах. При этом никакой работы с реальной БД быть не должно. Для того и применяется Mock, чтобы замокать реальную БД, подменив её фейковым кодом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrow. А можно тогда замаскировать не используя интерфейсы. Как я понимаю мне надо установить dbset, но что можно поставить на его месте?

Comment: [Testing with a mocking framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking)